# How to make my code more Pythonic?

Tags: python

I need to replace some letters into a List with numbers (each letter is encoded to a number). I used this structure:

```
r = []
for x in some_list:
    if x in "ABCDE":
        r.append({"A":10, "B":20, "C":30, "D":40, "E":50}[x])
    else:
        r.append(int(x)) # convert string digit to digit
some_list = r
```

(some_list being mutable as in this code).

I wish to ask if there are some more compact structures in python (less code) that can make this encoding and run faster.

Comment: Why aren't you doing an in-place replacement of the elements of some_list?  That would save you the over-head of copying.

Comment: what does that mean ? I am v. beginner to python !

Comment: It means instead of building a separate list r and then assigning it to some_list, you instead set each element of some_list to the new value in your loop.  However, there are some other responses with some very compact ways of doing this, so I recommend you follow up on those first.

Comment: you do know about http://codereview.stackexchange.com, this would be more appropriate there

Comment: You should try to distill a specific programming paradigm or technique or issue from your question - as it stands I'm voting to close this as too localized because from the title and question it's not really clear how future users would find this beneficial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
d = {"A":10, "B":20, "C":30, "D":40, "E":50}
some_list = [int(d.get(x, x)) for x in some_list]
```

Other ways to write that list comprehension include:

```
some_list = [d.get(x) or int(x) for x in some_list]
some_list = [d[x] if x in d else int(x) for x in some_list]
```

Comment: that call to int is not good, some_list is (as you can see above) comrised of letters. if the d.get defaults you will get a letter, which can not be cast as int.

Comment: @InbarRose: The `int()` is taken from the `else` clause in the OP's question, and serves exactly the same purpose.

Comment: I tested it and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can map each character to a number

```
l=[(ord(x)-ord('A')+1)*10 if x in 'ABCDE' else int(x) for x in some_list]
```

In a more general case you apply certain function that translates characters to letters

```
def f(c):
    if c in 'ABCDE':
        return (ord(c)-ord('A')+1)*10
    return int(c)

l=[f(x) for x in some_list]
```

Comment: Which could be rewritten as a list-comprehension: `[ord(x) - ord('A') + 1 if x in 'ABCDE' else int(x) for x in some_list]`